# play framework error: not found: type model

Tags: model, compiler-errors, playframework-2.0, migration, playframework-2.2

I'm migrating a 2.0 app to 2.2 in the play framework, the app can be found at: https://github.com/biesior/Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java

There is only one cryptic error when compiling:

```
\Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java-master\app\models\Event.java:14: **not found: type Model**
[error] public class Event extends Model {
[error]                            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed`enter code here`
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 28, 2013 12:32:00 AM
[FullCalendar] $
```

the file models/Event.java:

```
package models;


import com.avaje.ebean;
import play.data.format.Formats;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import play.db.ebean;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Event extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
```

plugins.sbt  file:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"



// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "FullCalendar"
  val appVersion = "1.1.2-Snapshot"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaEbean 
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here
  )

}
```

Any insight?

Thank you,.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your imports.

You have the `import com.avaje.ebean;` and `import play.db.ebean;` imports. Such imports are illegal. You may change them to `import com.avaje.ebean.*;` and `import play.db.ebean.*;` (or `import play.db.ebean.Model;` in particular) to get it working

Comment: Thank you. I am newer to this framework and Java as well. Is there a location to locate the required imports for such methods?

Comment: You should place the `import play.db.ebean.Model` statement in every `.java` file that uses the `Model` class.

Comment: ok, thanks. What are the exact imports I would need to get this to compile? Is there a resource to know which imports to include? (As I did not create it I do not know)